# Comparing the cell value to a range of multiple values in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm an amateur to a VBA  and currently working on a problem that if, for example, Range("Profesija") matches the value of the cell G4(that is a member of the range "G4:ED4") and the cell G5(or any cell below) contains a number, the value of the cell B5(that located on the same row as G5) is put to a cell Kaitigieee.

Here's my first draft:

```
Dim n As Range
Set n = Sheets("Matrix").Range("G4:ED4")
For Each c In n
If Range("Profesija") = n.value And n.value(0, -i) <> 0 Then
Range("Kaitigieee") = n.value(2, 0)
End If
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Currently I am stuck on debugging the following article of code:

```
Sub CopyData()
NewBook = ""
path = ThisWorkbook.path
Sheets("Staff").Select
For i = 2 To 100000
 If Cells(i, 1).value = "" Then
    i = 100000
Exit For
End If
Dim mainWB  As Workbook
Dim mainWS  As Worksheet

Dim n, c As Range

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim j As Long

Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set mainWS = mainWB.Sheets("Matrix")
LastRow = mainWS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 Set n = Sheets("Matrix").Range("G4:ED4")



  Name_file = path & "\" & Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 1).value & 
 Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 2).value & ".xls"
 Sheets("TEMPLATE_TARGET").Select


Range("Vardsuzvards").value = Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 1).value & " " & _
    Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 2).value & " "
Range("Personaskods").value = Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 3).value
Range("Dzivesvieta").value = Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 4).value
Range("Profesija").value = Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 5).value
For Each c In n
 If Range("Profesija").value = c.value Then
  For j = 1 To LastRow - c.Row
        If c.Offset(j, 0).value <> 0 Then
       Range("Kaitigieee").value = c.Offset(j, -3).value           ' From G5 
      to B5 is offset(0,-3)
        Exit Sub
        End If
    Next j
End If
Next c

Cells.Select
Selection.Copy

If NewBook = "" Then
    Workbooks.Add
    NewBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Else
    Workbooks(NewBook).Activate
    Cells(1, 1).Select
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
Name_file, FileFormat:=xlExcel8, _
Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
CreateBackup:=False
NewBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Workbooks("OVP_v1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Staff").Select

 Next i



 Workbooks(NewBook).Close

 MsgBox ("YAY")


 End Sub
```

The above mentioned code's cycle is being stuck on the middle of required sheet of data and keeps ignoring the command to define the "Kaitigieee" cell. I suppose that my problem is that I'm trying to collect a lot of data from two different workbook sheets at the same time, but I'm unsure how to fix it.

Comment: What are your Ranges here? Range("Profesija")  and Range("Kaitigieee"). Are they cells or range with different cells inside?

Comment: `n.value(0, -i)` what is `-i`?. That line makes no sense, at least for me. The arguments of value can be only `xlRangeValueDefault` or `xlRangeValueMSPersistXML` or `xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet`

Comment: Both "Profesija" and "Kaitigieee" refer to a one single cell.

Comment: Then I guess my answer should be what you need

Comment: Ok now I start seeing better: Are you aware that your 5 cells "Vardsuzvards" "Kaitigieee" are being overwritten with every loop? So from what I see you are not collecting a lot of data, but rather 5 cells.

Comment: The main idea was to keep the option to automatically score up the newly added records to preferred data sources open. But I am unsure how to remake the code to be able to collect data from approximately 200 records from now on.

Comment: Ok I try a new draft you ll tell me if it s closer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit blurry but I think this should correct your code:

```
Sub test()


Dim mainWB  As Workbook
Dim mainWS  As Worksheet
Dim n, c As Range
Dim i As Long

Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set mainWS = mainWB.Sheets("Matrix")


Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = mainWS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row      'Replace G by your longest Column

Set n = Sheets("Matrix").Range("G4:ED4")

For Each c In n
    If Range("A1").Value = c.Value Then
        For i = 1 To LastRow - c.Row
            If c.Offset(i, 0).Value <> 0 Then
            Range("A2").Value = c.Offset(i, -3).Value           ' From G5 to B5 is offset(0,-3)
            Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Note that I changed: Range("Profesija") by Range("A1") and Range("Kaitigieee") by Range("A2") in my example.

EDIT: Second Part

So first I added Option Explicit to make sure your dimensions are well entered (otherwise you might get errors)
Then I have changed your first for i to 100000 to a for to Lastrow. as I guess that s what you were doing anyway.

Finally the big change was in the addition of the cells.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData()

Dim mainWB  As Workbook
Dim mainWS  As Worksheet
Dim n, c As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Path, Newbook As String

Newbook = ""
Path = ThisWorkbook.Path

Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set mainWS = mainWB.Sheets("Matrix")
Set n = Sheets("Matrix").Range("G4:ED4")
LastRow = mainWS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Staff").Select

For i = 2 To LastRow

    Name_file = Path & "\" & Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 1).Value & Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 2).Value & ".xls"
    Sheets("TEMPLATE_TARGET").Select


    Range("Vardsuzvards").Value = Range("Vardsuzvards").Value + Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 1).Value + Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 2).Value ' I don't understand why you wanted the " " here
    Range("Personaskods").Value = Range("Personaskods").Value + Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 3).Value
    Range("Dzivesvieta").Value = Range("Dzivesvieta").Value + Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 4).Value
    Range("Profesija").Value = Range("Profesija").Value + Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 5).Value

        For Each c In n
            If Range("Profesija").Value = c.Value Then
                For j = 1 To LastRow - c.Row
                    If c.Offset(j, 0).Value <> 0 Then
                        Range("Kaitigieee").Value = Range("Kaitigieee").Value + c.Offset(j, -3).Value
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next c

    Cells.Copy

    If Newbook = "" Then
        Workbooks.Add
        Newbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Else
        Workbooks(Newbook).Activate
        Cells(1, 1).Select
    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Name_file, FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
    Newbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Workbooks("OVP_v1.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Staff").Select

Next i


Workbooks(Newbook).Close

MsgBox ("YAY")


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response; could you, please, give an advise in fixing the error of multiple For statements?

Comment: I am experiencing a few difficulties while trying to implement the above mentioned code into the major one, which have to contain several For Each operators.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you tried. I think my code works with a for each

Comment: Now tell me if it looks more like what you wanted

Comment: I was trying to correct the past code with above mentioned, but, unfortunately, it doesn't work accurately either. It does create a series of document templates as a result, but stores every single value from data source in each cell instead of one necessary.

Comment: I was going to ask one last thing - how it is possible to define the range("Kaitigieee"), so it would be equal to any value stored into the column B, that is located on the same row as j variable? I had an Activecell.offset operator in mind.